# class declaration Problem in IPhone SDk?

Tags: iphone

i have declared one class such as

```
 #import "CalcEntryVC.h"
 @interface initialcontroller : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{  
     IBOutlet BookmarkListTVC *bkcontroller;
         IBOutlet CalcEntryVC *calcentryVCController;
}
```

but when i declare in BookmarkListTVC.h
as

```
 @interface BookmarkListTVC : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate> 
 {

IBOutlet CalcEntryVC *calcentryVCController;
 }
```

the error comes **error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'CalcEntryVC'**

how can i overcome , i tried `#ifndef` also.....any solution pls?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done `#import "CalcEntryVC.h"` in BookmarkListTVC.h?

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to import the header as suggested in another answer.  YOu want to use the @class directive to declare CalcEntry as a forward declaration:

```
@class CalcEntryVC.h
```